# jenkins slave agent on ubuntu core

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

My Jenkins Master is hosted on a non windows machine and I want to run my Jenkins slave/agent on Ubuntu core 16, but to run a slave/agent on Ubuntu core we need java to be installed in ubuntu core. 
What is the right way to install java on ubuntu core because apt-get doesn't work on ubuntu core, neither could I find the java in snapcraft store

Comment: Ubuntu 16 has reached EOL, and is therefore [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: new to ubuntu but isn't it supported till 2024
https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle

Comment: Please read the article I linked: ***Under, 'questions you should avoid':*** "Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 and 16.10) and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange)."

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Core 16 and Ubuntu 16.04 are both LTS releases and thus fully supported until april 2021 (5y) with the option to buy "extended security maintenance" (ESM) for another 5 years ...

there is a java runtime environment https://snapcraft.io/java-jre-ondra that you should be able to use on armhf core installations.

Comment: I also used a similar approach I created a snap which installed onpen-jdk as side dependency and then set JAVA HOME from this snap. I didn't use anything from snapcraft store because none of them were from a known contributor account. Can you please add this also in your answer and I'll mark it as correct